# The respondents, 'which include' or 'who include'?

Tags: grammar, sentence

Would I say,'The respondents, which include funders and legislators' or '...who include funders and legislators'?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use "which" to refer to things; use "who" or "whom" (depending on the specific sentence construction) to refer to people.

> Cats, which are delightful animals, are found throughout the city as stray animals.
>
> Eclipse viewers who are focused on their technology to the exclusion of the event occurring above them are likely to have a less satisfactory experience on August 21.

Answer (score 0):

Respondent means " a person who answers a request for
information, which is why "who could be the  answer. But the sentence doesn't sound good to me. The full context might be helpful.

On the other hand,  "the respondents, which include funders and
legislators' " means " the respondents, including  funders and
legislators'.  Here "the funders" and "legislators " are in the list of respondents. This version, I think, fits well in your sentence.

Comment: Hm, why couldn't the words *respondents*, *funders* and *legislators* all refer to the *categories* (of people), in which case *which* would be more appropriate?

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for your comment.  I might have thought that way. I think the full context would  be helpful here. "  "Respondents, including funders and legislators', sounds better to me.